# How to share a firebase service across native and web?

Tags: angular, firebase, nativescript

For my web app I use firebase package and @angular/fire which I'm injecting into my service.
For NativeScript I should use nativescript-plugin-firebase.

All my services are using @angular/fire at the moment.

I tried to build the app for android and the result is a lot of different errors.

How can I share my firebase related services across web and native?

Comment: Please be more specific what are your errors. You may not able to use AngularFire with the {N} plugin, but you able to share the code if you use the common web apis.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"